# How to specify the fields that are shown in the marker popup in Maps?

Tags: leads

For Leads, currently, the popup shows the name of the lead in blue, in a large font. Underneath, in a smaller font, the address.

We would like to show the name of the company, not the person, of the lead. This sounds like an easy thing to do, but I can't seem to find it.

I found [this Salesforce document](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000389391&type=1), which tells me how to do it for a single Marker Layer. But I want to do it for all layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54S00000Jg5VtSAJ) and especially the answer by a Salesforce employee, this can be done by changing the `maps__Tooltipx__c` fields of `maps__MarkerLayer__c` objects.